# Navbar links should be all tall like the taller one

Tags: css

I have a navigation bar with 4 links floated.

While width of each one is 25% of total width of NAV, height is not fixed because text of a link could be longer than others and span across 2 rows, like in **[this example](http://jsfiddle.net/BB4M3/)**.

```
#first-level-navigation .mega-link {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 60%, #eaeeee 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 25%;
}

#first-level-navigation .mega-link a {
    color: #00643c;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I would like that height of smaller links will extend to height of taller one in case like mine, in which last link span on 2 rows if window is smaller enough. How to obtain it, withous forcing height in px? I tried with `height:100%` but it was unuseful

Comment: do you want to do that in jquery or just css ?

Comment: i will try nothing promised tho ;)

Comment: Thank you ;-) I thought about applying background to entire NAV instead of each links, but I did not try. Obviously in this case we must consider that clicked link (with class "active" in this case) will have a different background in order to differentiate itself

Comment: i found a way but for that the nav tag should have a fixed height :/ i will try to finde an other workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few years, new modern CSS techniques could be used to solve this issue, using **Flexbox Layout**.

Starting from **@Vucko**'s jsFiddle (proposed in its answer), I [slightly modified it](http://jsfiddle.net/ldetomi/BB4M3/14/) to use Flexbox in the following way:

```
#first-level-navigation{
    display:flex;
}

.mega-link{
    flex:1;
}
```

This code solve "*equal heights*" issue but to mantain also centered vertical alignment, is necessary to make flex also each `.mega-link`, so the complete code becomes the following:

```
#first-level-navigation{
    display:flex;
}

.mega-link{
    flex:1;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Please, note also that Flexbox allows to avoid specific declaration of fixed `width` (so `width:25%;` can be removed, replaced in its function by `flex:1;`), so becomes easier change number of `.mega-link` elements with auto adaptation of each one.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `display:table/table-cell`:

```
#first-level-navigation{
    display:table;
}

.mega-link{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BB4M3/10/)

Aslo, you have to add *browser prefixes* for `box-sizing: border-box` - [here's a good article about it by Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

Comment: Thank you perfect, but you forgot to specify that `float` on `.mega-link` must be disabled in order to have the correct fix! :-)

Comment: @LucaDetomi yea, sorry, I removed it because it isn't needed when you use `display:table-cell`. Glad to help :)

Comment: No problem. :-) but for other people, is important to highlight that `float` is not simply unnecessary, but must be removed, otherwise there is a conflict with `table-cell` :-)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery(in Coffeescript):

```
if $('html').length > 0
    link = $('.mega-link')

    # Determine heights
    link_height = link.height()

    # Applys heights
    link.css "height", link_height

    # when window resizes, calculate and apply again 
    $(window).on 'resize', ->
        # re-determine height
        link_height = link.height()

        # Apply heights
        link.css "height", link_height
```

Comment: Thank you, but if possible I prefer a css solution... :-)

Comment: off course, I understand. Consider this a last resort ;-)